# How can i get Local DateFormat with swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, date, timezone

I have CEST dates in **yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ** format. I want to show them in local format. The following function works fine. It shows the time correctly. 
But in the end I am forced to show the date in **"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"** format. How can i get Local/native DateFormat from iOS.

```
func changeTime()
    {
        myLabel.text = convertTimeZoneToLocal(timeZone: "CEST", date: "2017-09-27T18:25:42Z")
    }

func convertTimeZoneToLocal(timeZone:String, date:String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: timeZone)

    let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"  // I want to change this line.

    return dateFormatter.string(from: dt!)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use :

```
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
```

But these won't come in the same format `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm`

Answer (score 1):

```
// create dateFormatter with UTC time format
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-04-01T11:42:00")// create   date from string

// change to a readable time format and change to local time zone
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d, yyyy - h:mm a"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
let timeStamp = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
```

Comment: You're pushing **"EEE, MMM d, yyyy - h:mm a"** format again. I do not want to give a fixed format. I want to use whatever format the user has selected on the device. ;) I think the **.short**  format is going to work.

Answer (score 1):

> Use this to get the the formate base on selected region of OS

```
let dateformatter = DateFormatter()       
dateformatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("dd/MM/yyyy")
let strDate = dateformatter.string(from: NSDate() as Date)
```

> Output :
> OS Region is US : 18/02/2021
>
> OS Region is US : 02/18/2021